# How to solve $xy'=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+y$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve: $$xy'=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+y$$
And what would be the standard form to illustrate this situation? (e.g. $y' +P(x)y=Q(x)$ would be standard form of first order linear differential equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's slightly disguised, this is like a homogeneous differential equation. Try substituting $y=ux$ and rewrite this as a (separable) differential equation for $u$.